How to pass additional arguments to a dot net web api after authenticating with Entra ID
I'm writing a dot net web application and api which is using Entra ID for the authentication.  I've got the authentication working ok, and it successfully passes the access token from the application to the web api, but we will have two different types of users either internal or external.  The external clients will have a fixed account number which will restrict the details of the data they can see.  The internal users however can choose any account number from a dropdown list which they can masquerade as.
From the access token I can tell if a user is internal or external. If they are external I set the account number, but if they are internal they can choose the account number.  My problem is, how can I pass the account number back to the web application so it can pass it back on subsequent api calls?  Every call from an external client will have the same account number, but for internal clients they will have the ability from the application to choose which account they are connecting as (via another api endpoint)
My current thinking is for internal clients the web application will allow them to choose an account number via the api. The web application will then use that account number and pass it back to the api as a custom header (Client-Account-Number or similar).  The web api will then extract the value from that header after the client is authenticated.  I'm not sure if that is the best approach though.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Not sure, but I would try to try to set the custom Client-Account-Number through by passing it into the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationproperties, see if you can set this and if this is also available when you get back the tokens...
